# ProgressBar from vector

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying out my luck here with this question since it's kinda design related [*will request migration to stackoverflow it needed but I still believe these kind of questions could have their place here*].

I have created shape, saved it as an SVG and imported it in Android Studio as Vector Asset. I wanted to create a clip over it and use that as a progressDrawable for my progressBar but it kinda failed.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

My drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="256dp"
            android:height="630dp"
            android:viewportHeight="630.062"
            android:viewportWidth="256.997">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#000000"
                android:pathData="M128.9,57.09m-57.09,0a57.09,57.09 0,1 1,114.18 0a57.09,57.09 0,1 1,-114.18 0" />
            <path
                android:fillColor="#000000"
                android:pathData="M27,148.58C12.09,148.58 0,160.67 0,175.58v149.99c0,14.91 12.09,27 27,27s27,-12.09 27,-27V175.58C54,160.67 41.91,148.58 27,148.58z" />
            <path
                android:fillColor="#000000"
                android:pathData="M230,148.58c-14.91,0 -27,12.09 -27,27v149.99c0,14.91 12.09,27 27,27c14.91,0 27,-12.09 27,-27V175.58C257,160.67 244.91,148.58 230,148.58z" />
            <path
                android:fillColor="#000000"
                android:pathData="M127.99,133.58c-34.79,0 -63,-1.79 -63,33v226.49v6.5v203.49c0,14.91 12.09,27 27,27c14.91,0 27,-12.09 27,-27V425.42v-1.77c0,-4.97 4.03,-9 9,-9s9,4.03 9,9v1.77v177.64c0,14.91 12.09,27 27,27c14.91,0 27,-12.09 27,-27V399.57v-6.5V166.58C190.99,131.79 162.79,133.58 127.99,133.58z" />
        </vector>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Used in the layout:

```
<ProgressBar
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="90dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:max="100"
     android:progress="70"
     android:progressDrawable="@drawable/vector_progressbar" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution so far, even though it's a sort of a hack is to create a cut-out of my shape from a rectangle and color it the same as my background, wrap it inside a RelativeLayout and place the ProgressBar under it with with a small margin, that way, the only visible part of the progress bar is what is shown through the cut-out.

[image]

Comment: For now, from lack of answers I will mark this as the accepted answer till (if) someone else comes with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this for the solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/37022907/9114860

The way you have tried to create a custom progress bar will lead you to errors.
Follow this link to understand the XMLs created in the question asked in the above StackOverflow link.
https://www.zoftino.com/android-progressbar-and-custom-progressbar-examples

The `<clip>` solution given on the StackOverflow has a correction though i.e. instead of surrounding `<layer-list>` with `<clip>`, just surround the progress bar fill drawable with `<clip>` inside `<item android:id="@id/progress">`.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_progress_bar"/>   <!-- Your progress bar background drawable(SVG) here -->
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/ic_progress_fill" />  <!-- Your progress bar fill drawable(SVG) here -->
    </item>
</layer-list>
```